# Why is renderer2 not changing style in every html?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and TypeScript and right now I'm on a directives lesson. I had to change the style of one of my lists with directive. I have this directive in my app.

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appChecked]'
    })
    export class CheckedDirective implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void{
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'list-style-image', 'url(/assets/checked.png)');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'aquamarine');
      }
    }
```

In this file it works and it changes to new background color and new image URL:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="tasksList.length > 0; else noTasks">
    <p [ngStyle]="{color: getColor()}">Tasks: {{tasksList.length}}</p>
      <ul>
        <li appChecked *ngFor="let task of tasksList; let odd=odd; let last=last" [ngClass]="{'odd-li':odd==true, 'last-li':tasksList.length==1}">
          {{task.name}}
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteTask(task)">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="doneTask(task)">Done</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-template #noTasks>
      No Tasks<br>
    </ng-template>
```

But not in this:

```
<p>Tasks done: {{doneTaskList.length}} <br>
  
      <ul>
        <li appchecked *ngFor="let task of doneTaskList">
          {{task.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I was looking for anything I did wrong during the tutorial lessons, but I can't find anything.

Comment: looks like a typo... should be `appChecked` not `appchecked`

Comment: There is a typo issue for 2nd one, your selector is `appChecked` and not `appchecked`